# 2D Binary Search that accept random array sets

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary, 2d

```
public static int search(int[][] arr, int x){
  int row= arr.length, colum= arr[0].length-1;
  int lo=0, hi=row*colum;

    while(lo <= hi){
       int mid= lo+(hi-lo)/2;
         int mid_index= arr (mid/colum);
        if(mid_index == x){ 
               return mid;    
        }else if (x < mid_index) {
            hi= mid-1;
        }else if (x > mid_index){
            lo= mid+2;
        }
    }
              return -1;
}
   public static void main(String args []){
    int [][] arr = {{1,2,3,4}, 
                    {5,6,7,8}
                    {1, 7, 7, 95},
                    {9, 9, 80, 33}};
    int x = 95; 
    int result = search(arr , x);
    if (result == -1)
        System.out.print("Element is not present in array");
    else 
        System.out.print("Element is present inside the index:" +""+ result);}
```

*** Still learning this topic but need help. I don't know how i can make it search for the index position and accept random set of arrays.***

// Return -1 if target is not found

// supposed to print  11 as the target in this given is in index 12.

// Can perfectly run if the given array is empty.

// Can run even with the random set of arrays.

Comment: What is your definition of a *sorted* 2D array?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question.